# Response does not contain any data. PHP Script

Tags: php

I'm trying to work on my Login module on my project but it always returning

> **Response does not contain any data.**

I think the problem is my **DB_Functions.php** because I'm able to browse **index.php**.

Code for **DB_Functions.php**

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    public function getUserByEmailAndPasswordStudent($studentno, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_no = '$studentno'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $pass = $result['password'];
            // check for password equality
            if ($pass == $password) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for **index.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '' && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'studentlogin') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $studentno = $_POST['studentno'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPasswordStudent($studentno, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["user"]["studentid"] = $user["studentid"];
            $response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
            $response["user"]["mname"] = $user["mname"];
            $response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
            $response["user"]["student_no"] = $user["studentno"];
            $response["user"]["grade_level"] = $user["gradelevel"];
            $response["user"]["sectionid"] = $user["sectionid"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

What is wrong with my Code?

Comment: First, use `spl_autoload_register()` and second stop using `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated or removed, depending on the stable version

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks for the info but my deadline is really close, can't change for now.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `else branch` for condition when `$tag != 'studentlogin'` because you doesn't echo anything in this case. Your code should be like this:

```
if ($tag == 'studentlogin') {
    /* your code here*/ 
} else { 
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

If this solution doesn't help add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your file and add debug output to your question.